# Generating a random file name (just the name) in Python

Tags: python-3.x, temporary-files

I need a random file name to pass on to a command run with *subprocess*.

[mktemp](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html#tempfile.mktemp) was deprepcated in Python 2.3 and the documentation is telling us to use [mkstemp](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html#tempfile.mkstemp) instead.

However, since all I want is the filename I end up doing this:

```
fd, filename = tempfile.mkstemp(prefix='source', suffix='.wav')
os.close(fd)
```

which feels very unnecessary.

I guess I could just continue closing the file descriptor or just straight up ignore the deprecation warning and use `mktemp`, but I don't like using deprecated functions since they tend to be removed in the future - even though it survived 3.0. Neither feels like a good solution.

Any ideas that doesn't result in rewriting `mktemp`?

Answer (score 0):

You have a fonction call NamedTemporaryFile in the tempfile package in python 3. This function create a temporary file with a name attribute. 
in windows it have some limitation describe in the official python documentation https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/tempfile.html

I should have comment because I don't know if this really help. In you title you seems to want to only generate a name this method generate a temporary file. but in your example you create a tempfile so.. Hope it will help

Comment: `NamedTemporaryFile` does indeed open the file which is exactly what I want to avoid doing. Using it just replaces `os.close(fd)` with `file.close()`